# Visual Studio 2013 preview does not create an .exe from my .cpp

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to run my `.cpp` with the debug button, This error appears:

[image: error message]

It has worked fine for my other projects, but for some reason it just wont build a `.exe`, I don't know what happened. Someone please help.

Comment: It's most likely because there were some errors when building your program. You need to look at the error log and fix those build errors first.

Comment: No, there are no errors when I build it, but it still doesn't create an executable for some reason.

Comment: Ok, so i just found this thing that says I have 102 warnings in this thing called "Microsoft.CppBuilds.Targets", I have no idea what it is but its got a lot of code in it.